# Preventing form submission when input field is empty

Tags: javascript, html, forms

When no value is provided to the `roll` input field an alert is produced by the `empty()` function but this empty value is still passed to `retrive.php`. So how can I stop this from happening and only pass the value to `retrive.php` when some input value is provided?

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <title>STUDENT FORM</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function empty()
        {
          var x;
          x = document.getElementById("roll-input").value;
          if (x == "") 
           { 
              alert("Enter a Valid Roll Number");
           };
        }
    </script>
</head>
 <body >
  <h1 align="center">student details</h1>       
    <div id="input">
      <form action='retrive.php' method='get'>
       <fieldset>
        <legend>Get Details</legend>
          <dl>
            <dt><label for="roll-input">Enter Roll Number</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="roll" id="roll-input"><dd>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="empty()" />
          </dl>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to return false to cancel the submit.

```
function empty() {
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById("roll-input").value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Enter a Valid Roll Number");
        return false;
    };
}
```

and

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="return empty()" />
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FDPmn/)**

Answer (score 24):

How about using the required attribute?

```
<input id="Name" name="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" type="text" required/>
```

Only works in html5 though.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way is to add attribute "required" into the input tag

```
<input type="text" name="name" required>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method="post" name="loginForm" id ="loginForm" action="login.php">
<input type="text" name="uid" id="uid" />
<input type="password" name="pass"  id="pass" />
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Log In"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#loginForm').submit(function() 
{
    if ($.trim($("#uid").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#pass").val()) === "") {
        alert('Please enter Username and Password.');
    return false;
    }
});

</script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

i use with this I thinking it's maybe can help

```
  $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            if ($('input').val() === "") {
                alert('Please enter Username and Password.');
                return false;
            }
        });
    })
```

or work with class or ID like this

```
$('.inputClass')
$('#inputID')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save code you can simply do:

```
<input type="text" name="roll" id="roll-input">
<input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="return document.getElementById('roll-input').value !=''"/>
```

I just say.