# How to prevent an empty form submission into CakePHP 2.5.2

Tags: cakephp-2.5, cakephp-2.x

I am new to CakePHP, how can i use javascript to prevent a form being submitted empty, i mean with all fields empty ?

The user just hit the submit button

I am using CakePHP 2.5.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preventing form from submitting when input field is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953988/preventing-form-from-submitting-when-input-field-is-empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Javascript for such minor blank validation stuff. Just go through the validation section.

Check out this example below:

Model: User.php has the following validation code for email field.

```
class User extends AppModel {
  public $validate = array(
   'email' => array(
     'required' => true,
     'allowEmpty' => false,
     'message' => 'Email cannot be empty.'
     )
  );
```

---

Setting required to true, and allowEmpty to false does the job for you. Also, the "message" field acts as the icing on the cake which indicates the error message to be shown when the validation fails.

Peace! xD

Comment: Great you show some ligth over cake validation, did not know all the details you mention. 

I am thinking about using a count($this->passedArgs) and if 0 show a message. To not allow a empty form submission when the user does not fill any form field and hit the submit button. Or maybe cake has this feature out of the box ?

Comment: I think you might have mistaken the concept of $this->passedArgs with that of validation. We use $this->passedArgs to check out the arguments coming in the URL. Let's say we have an URL: http://localhost/calendars/view/recent/mark. pr($this->passedArgs) would return an array ->> Array
(
    [0] => recent
    [1] => mark
)

Comment: great a count on $this->passedArgs solve this problem