# jQuery Mobile fails to prevent the submit of an empty input field value

Tags: forms, validation, jquery-mobile, form-submit, trim

On my site built with jQuery Mobile v1.4.5 and jQuery 1.12.0 I have a **form input field** where a user can submit messages using the Return key (no explicit submit button). I want to **prevent the user of submitting an empty input** and I basically found [solutions for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953988/preventing-form-from-submitting-when-input-field-is-empty) here on Stackoveflow and reused code, but somehow *it still fails*, meaning my function still passes on empty input values.

Can anyone here spot the issue with my code regarding why the submit of an empty input field is still passing the validation?

```
<form id="formNewMessage" data-ajax="true" method="post" action="ajax_post_message.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="fromMobile" id="fromMobile" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="messageInput" id="messageInput" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Type your message here..." autocomplete="off">
</form>
<script>
$('#messageInput').keypress(function(e){
    if ((e.which == 13) && ($.trim($('#messageInput').val()) != "")) { // send message on Return, but prevent empty submits <-- this is not working :(
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // lock the input field
        $('#formNewMessage').submit(function(ev){
            $.ajax({
                type: $('#formNewMessage').attr('method'),
                url: $('#formNewMessage').attr('action'),
                data: $('#formNewMessage').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#messageInput').val(''); // clear the input field
                    window.location.reload(true); // reload the page
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   alert(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
            ev.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled'); // unlock the input field
    }
});
</script>
```

Thanks for any hints and tipps on fixing this issue!

Comment: replace this ($('#messageInput').val()) != "")) with this  ($('#messageInput').val()).length > 1))  -- that gets the length  (no of characters in the input) and checks if its greater than one.  it looks like at the moment its picking up the enter key as a character probably as a new line. Try > 2 if its not working as i think a new line is actually 2 characters eg (/n)

Comment: @Tasos amazing, thank you, it works using `.length > 1`! I had this in the code once but I can't remember why I changed it... Do you want to post your reply as answer to my question?

Comment: ok ill post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably its picking the Enter as a key hence its thinks the input is not empty

replace this

```
$('#messageInput').val()) != ""
```

with

```
$('#messageInput').val()).length > 1
```

that gets the length (no of characters in the input) and checks if its greater than one.