# Trying to stop add button from submitting if input field is empty

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a grocery list project that works similar to a todo list. I have an add button that inserts the input field value into an array and creates an li on the page. This works fine, but I'm trying to make it so that if the input field is empty, then an li isn't created. I've tried adding a check into my function but I can't get it working right. I'm not really sure if what I've tried here is the best way to go about it or if there's a better way to set up the check. I'd also like to know if there's a better way to setup the input field to submit on an enter click. What I have works, but I've read that this method is deprecated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Grocery List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Grocery List</h1>
    <input id="add-input" placeholder="Add Groceries" autocomplete="off">
    <button id="add-button">Add</button>
    <!--<button id="remove-button">Remove</button>-->
<div>
    <ul id="grocery-ul">

    </ul>
</div>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

let addButton = document.getElementById('add-button');
addButton.addEventListener('click', add);

let addInput = document.getElementById('add-input');
addInput.addEventListener('keydown', (key) => {
if(key.which == 13) {
add();
}
})

//let removeButton = document.getElementById('remove-button');
//removeButton.addEventListener('click', remove);

let groceryList = [

]

function add() {
groceryInput = addInput.value;
groceryList.push(groceryInput);
addInput.value = '';
displayGroceries();

if(groceryInput.length = 0) {
    addButton.disabled = true; 
} else {
    addButton.disabled = false;
}

}

function remove(event) {
let position = event.currentTarget.id;
groceryList.splice(position, 1);
displayGroceries();
}

function displayGroceries() {
let groceryUl = document.getElementById('grocery-ul');
groceryUl.innerHTML = '';

for (var i = 0; i < groceryList.length; i++) {
    let groceryLi = document.createElement('li');
    groceryLi.innerHTML = groceryList[i];
    groceryUl.appendChild(groceryLi);
     let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    removeButton.innerText = "Remove";
    removeButton.addEventListener('click', remove);
    removeButton.id = i;
    groceryLi.appendChild(removeButton);

    if(add.keyCode === 13) {
        add();
    }

  }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing form submission when input field is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953988/preventing-form-submission-when-input-field-is-empty)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check the input value, if the value is empty then return from the function:

```
function add() {
  groceryInput = addInput.value;
  if(groceryInput.trim() == ''){
    alert('Input field is empty');
    return true;
  }
  .....
  .....
```

*.....What I have works, but I've read that this method is deprecated.*

I think you wanted to mean the event here. The event [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) is deprecated but not [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) which you are using.

**Demo:**

```js
let addButton = document.getElementById('add-button');
addButton.addEventListener('click', add);

let addInput = document.getElementById('add-input');
addInput.addEventListener('keydown', (key) => {
  if(key.which == 13) {
    add();
  }
});

//let removeButton = document.getElementById('remove-button');
//removeButton.addEventListener('click', remove);

let groceryList = [];

function add() {
  groceryInput = addInput.value;
  if(groceryInput.trim() == ''){
    alert('Input field is empty');
    return true;
  }
  groceryList.push(groceryInput);
  addInput.value = '';
  displayGroceries();

  if(groceryInput.length = 0) {
      addButton.disabled = true; 
  } else {
      addButton.disabled = false;
  }

}

function remove(event) {
  let position = event.currentTarget.id;
  groceryList.splice(position, 1);
  displayGroceries();
}

function displayGroceries() {
  let groceryUl = document.getElementById('grocery-ul');
  groceryUl.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < groceryList.length; i++) {
      let groceryLi = document.createElement('li');
      groceryLi.innerHTML = groceryList[i];
      groceryUl.appendChild(groceryLi);
       let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
      removeButton.innerText = "Remove";
      removeButton.addEventListener('click', remove);
      removeButton.id = i;
      groceryLi.appendChild(removeButton);

      if(add.keyCode === 13) {
          add();
      }

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Grocery List</h1>
    <input id="add-input" placeholder="Add Groceries" autocomplete="off">
    <button id="add-button">Add</button>
    <!--<button id="remove-button">Remove</button>-->
<div>
    <ul id="grocery-ul">

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but could you explain why this works? I originally thought the check would have to return false for this to work. But, I just tried, and it works with either true or false. I'm really not sure why that is.

Comment: @CodeNoob91, the logic is simple here. If the input is empty then return from the function (*add()*) using `return true`, this will prevent the execution of the remaining code in the function:)

Comment: @CodeNoob91, you can accept the answer by *clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in*:)