# How to not change page when the login fields are empty

Tags: html

i'm adding a login system to my website i've figured out how to change pages but even if my login fields are empty when i click on my login button it changes page like i'm logged in while i'm not. Before adding the `a href='index.html'` when i was clicking the login button the site told me that i needed to fill the login field but now when i click even if the field are empty there's no error message and it changes page.
sorry if my explanations are a bit messy if you need more infos tell me ! :)
here's my code :

```
<form>
      <input type="email" class="input-box" placeholder="Email" required>
      <input type="password" class="input-box" placeholder="Password" required>
      <button type="submit" class="submit-btn"><a href="index.html">Login</a></button>
      <input type="checkbox"><span>remember me</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing form submission when input field is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953988/preventing-form-submission-when-input-field-is-empty)

Comment: simply learn about validation [Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-form-validation)

Comment: i'll check both links ty !

Comment: so i need to add a script it won't work anyways ?

Comment: If you validate with JavaScript only any person who knows developer tools can compromise your form (and possibly the whole webserver). You have to use some server-side validation at least and JavaScript is added for convenience.

Comment: so it'll be safer ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use several options to fix your problem.

1. As some others already suggested you can use JavaScript to validate the content of your input field. This is only on the client and wil leave your server still vulnerable to attacks. You should do a server validation too, with PHP for example and to be 100% safe a constraint validation for the database.
2. You could simple set constraint inside the HTML Tags:
   (min-length, max-length, pattern(RegEx))
   and so on.
   Check the [W3Schools site](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) for more detailed information.
   I would still use the aditional option from 1) to be safe!